# Live Boot via. Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, usb, live-usb

I made the mistake of overwriting my entire hdd with ubuntu 19.10 server on a laptop with no ethernet port :| and it has no wireless drivers pre-installed. I was wondering if there was a way that i could possibly access grub command line or Live boot from a USB on it? I've done a little searching but I can'ts find much.
Thanks

Comment: What computer is it (brand name and model)? What wifi chip is there (brand name and model)? What operating system do you want on this laptop? Can you make a live/install drive for that operating system? (Maybe you can use another computer for that purpose.)